# ¿Qué es "cocorichi"?

Tags: vocabulario, historia, méxico, comida, animales

En 1826 a la mina del Real de Guarisamey, Durango, México, se pagaban impuestos al introducir:

> sal, maíz, frijol, ciruelas, sandía, plátanos, uva, quesos, mezcal, chiles, cebollas, camotes, panocha, piloncillo, gallos, carne, unto y conservas.... membrillo, pera, guayaba, naranja, plátano, manzana, caña, nueces, repollo, raíces, miel, **cocorichi** (188), gallinas, reses, carneros, camarón, chicharrones, panelas, bizcochos, cajetas y jamoncillo.
>
> 188. No sabemos qué tipo de alimento es el cocorichi.
>
> -- *La vertiente occidental de la sierra: el último frente de colonización. 1760-1830* de Chantal Cramaussel

Aunque Cramaussel no lo reconoció, ¿podemos ahora identificar el cocorichi? (Y ¿hay alguna razón para creerlo masculino?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He estado investigando y, al parecer, *cocorichi* es como llamaban a los perros en alguna lengua indígena del noroeste de México. Si los usaban de alimento o no, no te lo puedo decir.

> (5) *Nombres de animales*
>
> ```
> Steffel     Español  Alemán  Hilton 1959  Brambila 1976
> ...
> cocorichi,  perro    Hund    cochí        kochí, okochí
> cocotschí
> ```
>
> - [*Las lenguas de México: Diálogos historiográficos*](http://www.bnm.unam.mx/files/iib/libros-electronicos/Lenguas_Mexico_Dialogos_Historiograficos.pdf) (p.243)
>     (La historiografía lingüística como ejercicio disciplinario compartido: la obra de Matthäus Steffel)

Comment: ¡Eso parece! De hecho Google me indicó una web de perros donde los listan por pedigrí y allí hay un tipu "cocorichi", por lo que sería algo usado actualmente.